# Meaning of "I am not for you to look into all issues"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, conversation

A question asked by a team member to a party outside team.. In response to that....

**Manager:** (Addressing me) This is the area where we need to be self sufficient. Please think about this, how to achieve this.

**I:** Sure. I was busy looking into another issue. I’ll look into this now.

**Manager:** I am not for you to look into all issues. I am looking at how we get people to look into issues themselves.

In last sentence, "I am not for you to look into all issues", 
Does she mean, she is looking into all issues and she can't do it anymore?

Comment: She means that she doesn't want you to be the one who always looks into everything.  She'd like everyone to be able to figure things out for themselves, and she'd like you to put some thought into how to achieve that goal.  The sentence is not grammatical as you've quoted it.  So it's not clear if she misspoke or you misquoted, but the intent seems clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

That sentence is nonsensical and incorrect as written.  I'm pretty sure your manager just had a slip of the tongue and *meant* to say:

> I am not *asking* for you to look into all the issues.

(You can substitute another verb in there:  "intending for you to..." or "saying for you to..." or something like that.  But it does need a verb to make it grammatical.)

The implication is that her concern is about the overall state of issues being handled within the team, and she's not saying you have to fix everything yourself.

Answer (score 0):

No. what she meant is

> She doesn't want you to take a look into all issues, people should be sensitive enough to look into their issues..